# What is the relationship between AsyncTask and Activity?

Tags: android

I have been given an assignment to develop an application that send server request and get response and then using JSON parsing, display the data content into a ListView.

I don't understand about AsyncTask and how to integrate all classes. Hope you will accommodate.
regards

Comment: -1 this shows no investigation and is not fit for this forum - try searching for some basic android tutorials - this is not the place for showing you everything about writing an app. Sorry.

Comment: @amjad -1 read the documentation first.(not a real question)

Comment: check this link.. this will solve your problem. [see this link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-asynctask-listview-json.html)

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't realize,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What should you do?

```
The first, send a request to server

The second, get response

The thirds, Parse data from InputStream which you got from Response

The fourth, show on ListView
```

Oh, done.
Right now,
Look into the first step.

How to send a request to server?

You can use **HttpURLConnection** or **HttpClient**

So, What's problem when you send a request to server?

I think you know when you send a request to server, you will get some problem: Network bad, InputStream from Server too large, ...

And how to resolve?

With single statement, you can't take along time to do. So with task which will takes along time to do, you have to handle in other thread. That's reason why we should use Thread or AsyncTask.

What's **AsyncTask**?

You can read more by search on Google. I just tell you: How to use AsyncTask to solve your spec.

What does **AsyncTask** do?

When you create an instance of **AsyncTask**,

It's will follow:

> -> Create -> PreExecute -> Execute (DoInBackground) - PostExecute

Ok.

Right now, I will answer your question:

Create an object which extends AsyncTask.

```
public class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, InputStream> {
    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {
        // You can implement this method if you want to prepare something before start execute (Send request to server)
        // Example, you can show Dialog, or something,...
    }
    @Override
    public InputStream doInBackground(String... strings) {
        // This is the important method in AsyncTask. You have to implements this method.
        // Demo: Using HttpClient 
        InputStream mInputStream = null;
        try {
            String uri = strings[0];
            HttpClient mClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet mGet = new HttpGet(uri);

            HttpResponse mResponse = mClient.execute(mGet);

            // There are 2 methods: getStatusCode & getContent.
            // I dont' remember exactly what are they. You can find in HttpResponse document.
            mInputStream = mReponse.getEntity().getContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TAG", "error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return mInputStream;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(InputStream result) {
        //After doInBackground, this method will be invoked if you implemented.
        // You can do anything with the result which you get from Result.
    }
}
```

Ok. Now we have to use this class

In your **MainActivity** or where you want to invoke this class, create an instance of this class

```
DownloadFile mDownloader = new DownloadFile();
mDownloader.execute("your_url");
```

Using method **mDownloader.get();** to get **InputStream** if you want to get. But you have to surround by **try-catch**

I know, if you want to use Dialog, you will search on Google how to show Dialog while download file from server.

And I suggest you that you should remember, you nead runOnUiThread if you want to Update UI.
Because an AsyncTask is Thread. So you can not Update UI if you are in another Thread which is not MainThread.

Comment: awesome,,,but dude, how to do json parse and inflate data into listview and to display??

Comment: what about the xml file? I need one button on which the url will be sent to server and data will be retrieved!

Comment: @Jack Duong You are too kind. ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709010/how-to-parse-json-responce-in-json-object-and-json-array-in-android/16709168#16709168
 
Please visit this link. You can understand something more about JSON & Parsing. :D

Answer (score 0):

**AsyncTask**

AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. It is used when you want to perform long awaited task in background.

It publish result on the UI thread(display result to the UI) without having to manipulate any threads or handlers.It means that user doesn’t bother about Thread management, everything is managed by itself. And thats why it is known as Painless Threading, see below point.

It is also known as **Painless Threading**.

The result of AsyncTask operation is published on UI thread. It has basically 4 methods to override: **onPreExecute, doInBackground, onProgressUpdate and onPostExecute**

Never expect to be a programmer by referring short notes, study deep..

Look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for **more detail.**

Comment: dude, i need some code instance about how to use it between server requesting and response.