# Connect To Server Database And pasrse data usind json parser

Tags: android, http, database-connection

Here is My code im trying to connect to server database but giving exception socketexception network nt reachable but it working for localhost pls help me wat is da problem in dis code

```
package com.example.test2;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

//import android.R;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
//import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    TextView resultView;
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        resultView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        //StrictMode.enableDefaults();
        getData();
    }

    public void getData(){
        String result = "";
        InputStream isr = null;
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()  , "1"   ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/xampp/connect.php");
            String str=httppost.toString();//YOUR PHP SCRIPT ADDRESS 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()  , str   ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext()  , "3"   ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            isr = entity.getContent();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            resultView.setText("Couldnt connect to database");
    }
    //convert response to string
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            isr.close();

            result=sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    //parse json data
   try {
       String s = "";
       JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

       for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
           JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
           s = s + 
                   "ID : "+json.getString("id")+" \nNAME : "+json.getString("name")+"\n\n";
       }

       resultView.setText(s);

   } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
       Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data "+e.toString());
   }

    }


}
```

Even i have taken Internet permission still i require any permissions

Comment: not working on real server but working on localhost?can you give us the real server link? maybe the problem is in the real server

Comment: you got your own domain?

Answer (score 2):

```
"http://localhost/xampp/connect.php"
```

U cannot put the localhost rather put ur ip address there.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/xampp/connect.php");
```

Change the localhost to your ip address like this:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("your ip address /connect.php");// where your ip address will be something like 192.168.14.4
```

To get ur ip address go to Start> type cmd> then in the screen that appears type  ipconfig.
If u are connected to WIFI look under WIFI under IPV4.
Also make make sure u put the server online!

Answer (score 0):

The problem will be solved if you put getData() in Thread.

example:

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        getData(); // If you want to update UI, please put Update UI into runOnUIThread
    }
});
```

But I don't suggest you use this way. Please use AsyncTask to solve.

Read more my answer in this question: [What is the relationship between AsyncTask and Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269754/what-is-the-relationship-between-asynctask-and-activity/18270369#18270369)